# MSG with IP list doesn't work

Tags: powershell, msg

I have a problem with an IP list for the `MSG` command in PowerShell.
I have something like this:

```
msg (Get-Content -Path C:\Users\user\Desktop\ip_list.txt) (Get-Content -Path C:\Users\user\Desktop\text4.txt)
```

In `ip_list.txt` there is `/server:10.0.1.119`, but it doesnt seem to work, even if I put `* /server:10.0.1.119` in it. The following does work, though:

```
msg * /server:10.0.1.119 (Get-Content -Path C:\Users\user\Desktop\text3.txt)
```

Any tips?

PS: AllowRemoteRPC is turned on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put just the IP addresses in the file `ip_list.txt` and run the command in a loop:

```
$msg = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\text4.txt'
Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\ip_list.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    & msg * /server:$_ "$msg"
}
```